# django inline issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

I have made a inline named as Fooinline. This inline was working fine in Django 1.02 but as soon as I upgraded to Django 1.1 it started giving an error:

```
**TypeError at /admin/casd/aaas/4028cb901dd9720a011deadd85e8007f/
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'**
```

My `Fooinline` code is:

```
class FooInline(InlineModelAdmin):

 template = 'admin/edit_inline/tabular2.html'

 def formfield_for_dbfield(self,db_field, **kwargs):
#    if isinstance(db_field, (models.ForeignKey, models.ManyToManyField)):
#        BaseModelAdmin.formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs)
#    else:
     kwargs['widget'] = FlatTextWidget
     return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
```

And my `FlatTextWidget` is

```
class FlatTextWidget(HiddenInput):
 def __init__(self, attrs=None):
     if attrs is not None:
         self.attrs = attrs.copy()
         super(Widget, self).__init__(attrs)
     else:
         self.attrs = {}
         super(Widget, self).__init__()

def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
    real_field = super(HiddenInput, self).render(name, value, attrs)
    x = value
    if x is None:
        x = ''
    return mark_safe( '%s%s' % (real_field, x) )

def _has_changed(self, initial, data):
    return False
```

I am calling my `Fooinline` as

```
 class XYZInline(Fooinline):
    model=XYZ
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your `formfield_for_dbfield`, it should read:

```
def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
    kwargs['widget'] = FlatTextWidget
    return super(FooInline, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field,**kwargs)
```

Take a look at the original function in [contrib/admin/options.py#L71](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L71)